# Paged Custom ComboBox

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2005

I would like to have some sample code on how to do a paginated ComboBox.
My data consist on 1300+ items. When the user clicks the combo box arrow, the combobox will display display 25 (page size configurable) items at the time with arrows up/down (depending on page location) so that the user can request the previous/next page.
The data is coming from a generic list.(List)

Thus, the idea is to display only a subset of the data at the time.The user can scroll and select from the list as per normal combobox.  At the top and bottom of the list should be a new button to request the previous or next page of navigator values.

Note: All data is read only. For legacy issues I can only use Winforms (.net 2.0) and C# but VB.net code will do as well

Comment: so you know of a library and aren't sure? have you started this and are having problems? or you just want someone else to do the work for you?

Comment: No I am not aware of any library/open source component. I am at the planning/design stage. No need for someone else to do it.

Comment: A few questions : 1. even in .NET 2.0, a ComboBox easily supports 1300 entries, scrolls very fast : you can easily set the height of the DropDown to match the number of default items you want to display, and you can use the PageUp, PageDown, End, Home keys to move the display position : with all that functionality built-in to the control itself, may I ask why you want this to be "paged" ? 2. Why do you wish to add buttons that duplicate the behavior of the PageUp/Down, etc. keys ? 3. What "mode" are you using the ComboBox in : i.e., : what 'DropDownStyle property are you using ?

Comment: I just checked with the user with a small protoytpe and it will work fine using PageUp/down thanks Bill

Answer (score 0):

you might want to consider using a treeview as a dropdown control for your combobox, smth like is done here:

[image]

you can get source code for this control here:  [ComboBox control with a TreeView](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=3700&lngWId=10) I guess it should give an idea on how to proceed with your task

regards

Comment: No need, see comment above.
Thank you for your time, I am actually thinking of another project that can benefit of this treeview combo box